# Set values of a Firebase data array using Polymer

Tags: arrays, firebase, polymer, 2-way-object-databinding

**Problem:** 
I want to try to have multiple games running at the root of my Firebase, they all have Firebase generated id's, 

when I'm trying to fetch them using the `<firebase-collection>` I'm always getting an array of the Objects, and 2-way binding is very hard with Polymer.

**Is there a way to get the Firebase data as an Object?**

I tried to add the `data-as-object` attribute, but it didn't worked, I also got an array.

I even tried to use the `<firebase-document>` element by simply change form 
`<-collection>` to `<-document>`, but then updating the game data didn't push to firebase. 

I don't know if this is possible ...

**Or is there a way for good two-way binding?** 

I can't use the index of the array item, like this: `this.set('gameData.' + i)`, because then I'm getting the error `Uncaught Error: unexpected key 2`, when I try to modify the values under the Object in the array

Full code on [Github](https://github.com/DeepSpaceDev/TMP/tree/Multiple-players)

**My code:**

*Data provider:*

```
<firebase-collection location="https://***.firebaseio.com" 
                     data="{{data}}" data-as-object log>
</firebase-collection>
<!-- script -->
Polymer({
    is: 'tmp-game-data',
    properties: {
        data: {
            notify: true
        }
        }
});
```

*Game Element:*

```
<!-- map with several players(Array), -->
<!-- an player(Object) has some properties -->
<!-- on-map-ready, when the map is fully configured --> 
<tmp-map players="{{game.players}}" 
         on-map-ready="_mapReadyCallback">
</tmp-map>
<!-- menu user for creating and -->
<!-- joining games with selected settings -->
<tmp-menu on-start-global-game="startGlobalGame" 
          on-join-game="joinGame">
</tmp-menu>
<tmp-game-data data="{{gamesData}}"></tmp-game-data>
<!-- script -->
var blocks = []; //Map blocks, global access

Polymer({
    is: 'tmp-game',

    properties: {
        gamesData: {
            notify: true
        },
        game: {
            notify: true
        },
        gameId: {
            type: String
        }
    },

    startGlobalGame: function(e) {
        var gameId = getRandomString(6);
        this.set('gameId', gameId);

        var player = {id: /*playerId*/};
        var players = [player];

        this.push('gamesData', {
            gameId: gameId,
            maxPlayers: e.detail.maxPlayers,
            players: players
        });

        this.selectGame();

        //generate map
    },

    joinGame: function(e) {
        var gameId = e.detail.gameId;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.gamesData.length; i++) {
            if(this.gamesData[i].gameId === gameId) {
                var map = this.get('gamesData.' + i + '.map');
                //generate map with the map of the game
            }
        }
        this.selectGame();
    },

    selectGame: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.gamesData.length; i++) {
            if(this.gamesData[i].gameId === this.gameId) {
                this.set('game', this.gamesData[i]);
                this.linkPaths('game', 'gamesData.' + i);
            }
        }
    },

    _mapReadyCallback: function(e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.gamesData.length; i++) {
            if(this.gamesData[i].gameId === this.gameId) {
                //get the map as a json
                var map = JSON.stringify(blocks);
                this.set('gamesData.' + i + '.map', map);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I removed `<dom-module>`, `<template>` and `<script>` to simplify the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to manipulate the data as Object instead of Array...

In your snippet, you do not specify the Array type for `data` and `gamesData`

You will have to use Polymer API to manipulate the Array you get through data-binding, like `this.push`, `this.splice`, etc... like you did already.

You should also be able to `this.set('gamesData.' + i + '.map', map);` like described [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding)

Comment: I thought of the `<firebase-collection>` attribute `data-as-object`, but unluckily it isn't working ... 
Ohh yeah I've added it, but does it matter, when I don't define the type?
The problem, when you're working with firebase, you can't use the `splice`, because Firebase then creates a new Object with changed properties and leaves the element you wanted to delete as it is on his servers ... 
And last I'll get an error (added above) on `this.set('gamesData.' + i + '.map', map);` I don't know exactly what it means, because I works apparently the way it is supposed!

Comment: there is no such attribute! :) I am building a set of element that extends Firebase, it might interest you, and I will build also a demo out of it, I'll keep you updated. In the meantime, check out here: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended

Comment: But why can I find it here? [Polymer Elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element#dataAsObject)

Comment: dataAsObject is an acessor function defined in the behavior but only used by firebase-document

Comment: it should not even be public, just a small bug, I'll raise a small issue on that point!

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I wondered what it supposed for and wondered why it doesn't work for me :'D